# Email sent to root: "Output from from your job 1843" - "Killed"

Tags: logs, signals, at, sigkill

I run a Sheevaplug (small ARM server) with Debian 9.  It does not have any third-party repos enabled in `sources.list` / `sources.list.d`.

I have a backup script which runs as `root`, and uses `at`.  I think something broke on Sep 13, because I am getting these emails that look like they come from `at`.  They are daily, like my backups.  The body of the message just says `Killed`.

I can't think what would be sending SIGKILL to my process!  Without gathering any more information than I have now, can you think of *any* reason this would happen?

It can't be from the OOM killer (Out of Memory condition), because I have a full kernel log in `dmesg` which does not show any OOM messages.

The `at` job is

```
#!/bin/sh
# at uses sh shell

set -e                   
cd /d/backup/jenkins-desktop/

for i in */; do                              
    nice ionice -c 3 rdiff-backup "$i" ../jenkins-desktop.rdiff/"$i"
done
```

I doubt it's systemd `SystemCallFilter=`, and that would send SIGSYS by default.  I see that a couple of `rlimit`s send SIGKILL.  But I'm not doing anything to set `rlimit`s myself; also it looks like in both cases you would be killed by SIGXCPU first, which defaults to fatal and should show "CPU time limit exceeded".

I have looked in `journalctl --since=-2d -p notice` and there are no errors, only some success messages from `anacron`.

---

```
Return-path: <root@brick>
Envelope-to: root@brick
Delivery-date: Thu, 13 Sep 2018 02:14:15 +0100
Received: from root by brick with local (Exim 4.89)
        (envelope-from <root@brick>)
        id 1g0GD0-0000Xr-Bz
        for root@brick; Thu, 13 Sep 2018 02:14:14 +0100
Subject: Output from your job     1843
To: root@brick
Message-Id: <E1g0GD0-0000Xr-Bz@brick>
From: root <root@brick>
Date: Thu, 13 Sep 2018 02:14:14 +0100
X-IMAPbase: 1541805998 113
Status: O
X-UID: 1

Killed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The body of the message just says `Killed`.

Sorry, this was incorrect.

The body of the *first* message says `Killed`.  I think this was a one-off killing performed by an admin (me) :-).

The reason I am getting daily messages can be investigated by looking at the subsequent messages.  Or, I should be careful now and say the second and last messages look the same :-).

```
Previous backup seems to have failed, regressing destination now.
Exception '[Errno 28] No space left on device' raised of class '<type 'exceptions.IOError'>':
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdiff_backup/robust.py", line 32, in check_common_error
    try: return function(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdiff_backup/restore.py", line 468, in get_fp
    Rdiff.write_patched_fp(current_fp, delta_fp, new_fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdiff_backup/Rdiff.py", line 73, in write_patched_fp
    rpath.copyfileobj(librsync.PatchedFile(basis_fp, delta_fp), out_fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdiff_backup/rpath.py", line 64, in copyfileobj
    outputfp.write(inbuf)

Exception '[Errno 28] No space left on device' raised of class '<type 'exceptions.IOError'>':
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdiff_backup/Main.py", line 304, in error_check_Main
    try: Main(arglist)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdiff_backup/Main.py", line 324, in Main
    take_action(rps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdiff_backup/Main.py", line 280, in take_action
    elif action == "backup": Backup(rps[0], rps[1])
```

You might wonder "regressing destination" seems to fail with "No space left on device".  I'm not sure, because there seems to be a fair amount of space on the drive, but that's a question for another day.